# An App ID with Identifier 'com.companyname.appname' is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, testflight

I am trying to upload my IOS app to TestFlight for beta testing. On XCode, my application's bundle ID is **com.companyname.appname**. When i try to create a distribution provisioning profile, i am told to create an app ID.

When i try to register an IOS App ID on the developer portal, i enter *appname* under **App ID Description** and *com.companyname.appname* under **Bundle ID**. I get the error message

```
There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
An App ID with Identifier 'com.companyname.appname' is not available. 
Please enter a different string.
```

I currently have no other app with bundle ID **com.companyname.appname**. When i change the bundle ID to some other string like **com.companyname.io**, it works.

Why doesn't the bundle name **com.companyname.appname** work?

Should i go ahead and use a different bundle id from what is on XCode?

Am i even going about this right?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `com.companyname.appname` in your question as a placeholder for the real string you've entered in the portal, or that's really what you're using?

Bundle ID's need to be globally unique. Not just unique to you. So someone else is likely using the same `com.companyname.appname` as you've used.

You should be using a Bundle ID that's based on your domain name (in reverse order). For example, if your domain name is `someguyfortune.com`, and your app is called `MyAwesomeApp`, then you should use a Bundle ID of `com.someguyfortune.MyAwesomeApp`. Case matters. I personally prefer using all lower case letters, but Xcode will use uppercase letters by default and they work fine.

Using this reverse domain name style improves the odds that no one else will be using the same Bundle ID.

Comment: `com.companyname.appname` is a placeholder. I would be surprised if someone else has used it. The company name and app name are very unique.

Comment: I've seen cases where other developers on a team have added the Bundle ID to their personal accounts when working on a corporate app, not realizing that they're causing a conflict later. Similar with third party contractors. And I had someone else register the Bundle ID I used in an open source project. Best to just change yours and move on.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely means there is already a bundle identifier with the same value.  Bundle identifiers must be unique.

Comment: If i rename the bundle identifier on the developer profile, it'll be different from what is on XCode. Is that fine?

Comment: No, your app in Xcode and in the developer/provisioning profile must be the same.  If you change one, you'll need to change the other to match it.