# why I can't find my App Id in the Apple Developer member center

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-id

I want to implement push notification by following a tutorial and I need to make an App ID in Apple developer account.

[image]

This is the very first time I register an App ID and I am very sure other people will not have the same bundle ID. But it is said that bundle ID id.monstera.mHRIS has already taken.

[image]

And I can't find my App ID on the dashboard.

[image]

I suspect because I automatically manage signing in Xcode.

[image]

I need to find my App ID so I can enable "push notification" and I need to see the App ID Prefix. How to find my App ID if I automatically manage signing?

If I change My Bundle ID, it is said

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48351042/144857 . And it looks like you may be your own second teammate that's created the duplicate. Are you logged into Xcode with the same Apple ID that you're using for the developer portal?

Comment: Your Xcode Screenshot shows that you have enter bundle id :- `id.monstera.mHRIS` and in your apple account App ID is `id.monit.mHRIS`. Both are different